# Wordpress gutenberg block to call external API

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I’m trying to create a Wordpress Gutenberg block, which will fetch external API like this:

```
apiFetch( { path: '//gorest.co.in/public/v1/users' } )
  .then( (response) => {
    setState({users: response});
  } );
```

and endup with error:

```
{
  code: "rest_no_route"
  data: {status: 404}
  message: "No route was found matching the URL and request method."
}
```

When I try to call an internal WP API works:

```
apiFetch( { path: '/wp/v2/users' } )
  .then( (response) => {
    setState({users: response});
  } );
```

Is there a way a Wordpress Gutenberg block to call an external API?

Comment: The `path` is shorthand and is appended to the root URL. Try using `url:  'https://gorest.co.in/public/v1/users'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `url` instead of `path`. `path` is the shorthand version of the API endpoint. When calling the endpoint, the `path` is appended to the root URL. That's why the `/wp/v2/users` works for you. Since it's giving you the full path to the endpoint.

Using `url` will use the full URL instead and allow connection to external APIs.

```
apiFetch( { url: 'https://gorest.co.in/public/v1/users' } )
  .then( (response) => {
    setState({users: response});
  } );
```

[Here is the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-api-fetch/#path-string)